# How to change default logo of magento admin panel

Tags: magento2, theme, login, backend, admin-panel

[image: login and after login logo not appeared]How to change default logo of magento admin panel

[image: HomePage]

Comment: To modify the default admin logo with custom theme, [check here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/206125/61183).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is no setting to change Magento's backend logo.
If you want, you can change it by replacing at:

```
<magento_root>/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/images/magento-logo.svg
```

Note: Where `<magento_root>` is the path of your Magento installation.

**Update:** As @matinict said, above solution is not a permanent solution. So below is the correct approach.

First, you need to create a custom admin theme and then change the logo.

Steps are listed below:

> 1. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/registration.php

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    '[VendorName]_[ModuleName]',
    __DIR__
);
```

> 2. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/etc/module.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="[VendorName]_[ModuleName]" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Theme"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

> 3. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/etc/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Theme\Model\View\Design">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="themes" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="adminhtml" xsi:type="string">[VendorName]/[themename]</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

> 4. app/design/adminhtml/[VendorName]/[themename]/registration.php

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'adminhtml/[VendorName]/[themename]',
    __DIR__
);
```

> 5. app/design/adminhtml/[VendorName]/[themename]/theme.xml

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>Theme Title</title>
    <parent>Magento/backend</parent>
</theme>
```

> 6. app/design/adminhtml/[VendorName]/[themename]/Magento_Backend/layout/admin_login.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-login" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="styles" />
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="logo">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="logo_image_src" xsi:type="string">images/login-logo.svg</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

> 7. Upload **`app/design/adminhtml/[VendorName]/[themename]/web/images/login-logo.svg`**
> 8. app/design/adminhtml/[VendorName]/[themename]/Magento_Backend/layout/default.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header">
            <referenceBlock name="logo">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">300</argument> 
                    <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">300</argument>
                    <argument name="show_part" xsi:type="string">logo</argument>
                    <argument name="edition" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Community Edition</argument>
                    <argument name="logo_image_src" xsi:type="string">images/menu-logo.svg</argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> 9. Upload **`app/design/adminhtml/[VendorName]/[themename]/web/images/menu-logo.svg`**
> 10. Magento CLI

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

**Note:** You can change the names of logo files in the configuration file if you want to use PNG files instead of SVG for the logo.

**Note:** Reference taken from [Magento admin logo change!](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/206100/magento-admin-logo-change/206125#206125)

Comment: But in chrome it look like this. The logo won't appear in chrome

Comment: Convert your image into .svg file

Comment: its not permanent sulotion

Answer (score 5):

Logo is coming up from magento2-base/setup/pub/images/magento-logo.svg .

Comment: But in chrome it look like this. The logo won't appear in chrome

Comment: Very nice. It worked for me. thanks for saving my time.

Answer (score 3):

in magento 2, changing logo in pub/static folder is not an appropriate option, to change Admin Section logo you need to create an admin theme :

**Step 1** :
create your theme folder:
app/design/adminhtml/[Vendorname]/[Theme-name]/

**Step 2** :
create theme **registration.php** and **theme.xml** files within [Theme-name] folder.

content for **registration.php**

```
<?php
 \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
'adminhtml/[Vendorname]/[Theme-name]',
__DIR__
);
```

content for **theme.xml**

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
<title>My Admin Theme</title>
<parent>Magento/backend</parent>
</theme>
```

**Step 3** :
Create folder **Magento-Theme** and layout:
app/design/adminhtml/[Vendorname]/[Theme-name]/Magento_Theme/layout/

**Step 4** :
create **default.xml** with code below :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
* Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <title>Admin Title</title>
</head>
<body>        
    <referenceContainer name="header">
        <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Page\Header" name="logo" before="-">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="show_part" xsi:type="string">logo</argument>
                <argument name="edition" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Community Edition</argument>
                <argument name="logo_image_src" xsi:type="string">images/my-logo.svg</argument>
                <argument name="logo_alt" xsi:type="string">My Admin  Panel</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>            
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

**Step 5** :
upload your logo (**my-logo.svg**) in **web/images** folder:

upload path:
app/design/adminhtml/[Vendorname]/[Theme-name]/web/images/

**That's it..**
Now upload your theme and run and clear cache "**Flush Cache Storage**"

Hope this will help !

Comment: missing the </theme> in the theme.xml file (it generates an error). Other then that, this works.

Comment: Thanks @Spyrule for pointing out, sorry </theme> tag was missed from code block.

Comment: good logic but not work for me

Comment: Works great for me on 2.4.3-pl.

Answer (score 0):

credits : @adnan Khaliq

Very Simple to change the magento backend logo.

1. right click on the magento backend logo.
2. click on ' copy image address'
3. paste it in the browser. you will get the exact logo address in the address bar.
4. follow the path in ftp/cpanel/file-zilla and upload your logo.

Comment: But in chrome it look like this. The logo won't appear in chrome

Answer (score 0):

Here the URLs list for the Magento admin & login box

To overwrite the img follow the docs:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-general.html

The Pub folder and files are generated by Magento dinamically.

-

[![logos login][2]][2]

Answer (score 0):

On the page "[Create an Admin theme](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/themes/admin_theme_create.html)" there is a section "Admin theme logo (optional)", where is described creating "admin_login.xml" file for "admin-index" page (log-in) for changing logo in the "log-in form".
With creating "admin_login.xml" file, its content and applying there are no problems. Custom logo is used.  
In that section there is a reference to "[Declaring theme logo](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html#logo_declare)", where the procedure of changing a default logo is described, which is displayed on the page "admin-dashboard" in the top left corner.  
For declaring a new logo a file "default.xml" is used, where in the tag "argument" a wrong value of the attribute "name" is written.  
Instead of "logo_image_src" there is written "logo_file", using of which doesn't change the logo, that is displayed on the page "admin-dashboard" in the top left corner.  
Changing the "name"-attribute value from "logo_file" to "logo_image_src" corrects the situaton and small logo is also changed.

Don't forget about:

1. sudo bin/magento setup:upgrade
2. sudo bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
3. sudo bin/magento cache:flush

Update.  
In "frontend" area the situation with "name"-attribute value of the "argument"-tag in the file "default.xml" is opposite. Working value is "logo_file", as it is shown on the web-site, and the value "logo_image_src" doesn't change the logo. Other tags work, for example, "argument"-tag where "name"-attribute value is "logo_alt".  
I don't know the reason why it happens so. But in my "Magento 2" admin theme "logo_image_src" value works in files "admin_login.xml" and "default.xml". And in frontend area in the file "default.xml" the value "logo_file" works.

Answer (score 0):

Create New Module, example, `app/code/Theshreyas/Adminlogo`

place your image in the following path : `Theshreyas/Adminlogo/view/adminhtml/web/images/logo-wide.png`
create `Theshreyas/Adminlogo/view/adminhtml/layout/admin_login.xml` with following content

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-login" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="styles" />
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="logo">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="logo_image_src" xsi:type="string">Theshreyas_Adminlogo/images/logo-wide.png</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

for changing other custom admin logos check my [module](https://github.com/theshreyas/magento-2-quickies/tree/main/Adminlogo)