# Magento 2 - Change Magento Logo on the admin page

Tags: magento2, admin-login

I want to change Magento Logo in the admin login page, can somebody tell me how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please see on this [question link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/126109/how-to-change-default-logo-of-magento-admin-panel), you need to create new theme and image should be svg format, maybe it's little complex but if you really want to change the logo you must try solution in that link, and feel free again to ask if you get trouble.